# how to change shapes when clicking menu items in java

Tags: java, swing, shapes, paintcomponent, menubar

I am having a problem changing the shapes displayed when the user clicks on the menu item in java using the JFrame. Can anyone suggest how I can solve this? Below is my code:

```
public class PlayingWithShapes implements ActionListener
{
    protected JMenuItem circle = new JMenuItem("Circle");
    protected String identifier = "circle";
    public PlayingWithShapes()
    {
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu shapes = new JMenu("Shapes");
    JMenu colors = new JMenu("Colors");

    circle.addActionListener(this);
    shapes.add(circle);
    menuBar.add(shapes);
    menuBar.add(colors);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Playing With Shapes");
    frame.setSize(600,400);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(new Shapes());
    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           new PlayingWithShapes();
        }
    };
    EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable);

}
```

I want to change the shape as circle when clicking on the circle menuItem

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent click) {

   if(click.getSource() == circle){
      Shapes shape = new Shapes();

   }
}

public class Shapes extends JPanel
{
```

How can I then call rectangle?

```
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics shapes)
    {
        circle(shapes);
    }

    public void circle(Graphics shapes)
    {
        shapes.setColor(Color.yellow);
        shapes.fillOval(200,100, 100, 100);
    }
    public void rectangle(Graphics shapes)
    {
        shapes.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        shapes.fillRect(200,100,100,100);
    }

}

}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Question tags changed: your question has really nothing to do with NetBeans (the IDE) and all to do with Swing (the graphics library).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestions:

- Don't create a new Shapes JPanel within your actionPerformed as this achieves nothing.
- Instead within actionPerformed change the state of a field of the class, and base the drawing within your paintComponent method on the state held by that field.
- For instance, if you only have two different types of shapes, the above field could simply be a boolean, perhaps called `drawRectangle`, and in actionPerformed you'd change this to true or false and call `repaint();`. And then in you'd use an if block within paintComponent drawing a Rectangle if it is true or a oval if not.
- If you want to have the ability to draw multiple different shapes, create an enum and make the field discussed above a field of this enum type. Then use a switch statement within paintComponent to decide which shape to draw.
- If you want to show different shapes at the same time, then you'll need to create a collection of Shape such as an `ArrayList<Shape>` and add Shape-derived objects to this collection, and then iterate through it in a for loop within paintComponent using a Graphics2D object to draw each Shape. I don't think that you need this right now.
- Don't forget to call the `super.paintComponent(g);` within your method override.

i.e.,

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if (drawRectangle) {
        rectangle(g);
    } else {
        circle(g);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for such response. Yeah I was thinking about boolean but sadly I have 4 shapes. Can you please give an example of the enum?

Comment: @JayGorio: Give it a try on your own first, and then show us your attempt. You won't regret trying this out, and I have confidence that you can do it.

Comment: Thanks, but I m getting this error with the ;super.paintComponent();

Comment: Ah okay got it thanks so much for the idea. Instead of using switch I make used of if condition and call the method inside the paintComponent. Again thank you.

Comment: @JayGorio: but it is important to also call the super's method, else the prior drawings won't be removed.

Comment: yeah. But I didnt call the super I just used the repaint() method. But yeah it's important.

Comment: How about if I want to change the color of the selected shape? Let's say for example I selected circle when I click on red it will turns red and if I click violet it will turns violet and so on..?

Comment: @JayGorio: That's a new problem and deserves a new question on this site one that again shows your code attempt. For this you'll need to use a MouseListener added to the drawing JPanel and some more if statements within the paintComponent method. Also search this site for similar questions as they've been asked, and I and others including MadProgrammer have answered them in the past.